# state undefined input form react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, undefined

I have a controlled form in React, binding the value. When I try to use the state value, I return undefined.
I want to get the value informed in the input of the form, to use it in test in the component's functions.
Follows code.

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import {Button,Form,Card,Modal,Spinner} from 'react-bootstrap';
import CodigoValidacao from './components/codigoValidacao';
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
   this.handleInputChangeCodigo=this.handleInputChangeCodigo.bind(this);
   this.validaCodigo=this.validaCodigo.bind(this);

   this.state = {
     CodigoDigitado: '',
  }
}
handleInputChangeCodigo(event){

   this.setState({CodigoDigitado: event.target.value})
   console.log('Digitando: '+ this.state.codigoDigitado)
}
validaCodigo(){
   let codDigi = this.codigoDigitado;
   console.log(this.state.CodigoValidacao + ' - ' + this.state.codigoDigitado +' - '+ codDigi);
 }
render(){
   return (
      <CodigoValidacao handleInputChangeCodigo={this.handleInputChangeCodigo}
                                                    codigoDigitado={this.state.CodigoDigitado}
                                                    validaCodigo={this.validaCodigo}
   );
  }
}
```

CodigoValidacao.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Form, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';

class codigoValidacao extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }

    render(){
       return(
         <Form>
            <Form.Group controlId="codigoVerificacao">
              <Form.Label style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>
                Código de Verificação
              </Form.Label>   
              <Form.Control type="text" value={this.props.codigoDigitado}
                                        onChange={this.props.handleInputChangeCodigo}
                                        placeholder="código de verificação" />
              <Button variant="primary" onClick={this.props.validaCodigo}>
                Valida
              </Button>
            </Form.Group>
          </Form>  
       );
     }
}

export default codigoValidacao;
```

FireFox Console Output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RL3WK.jpg)

Comment: watch capital letters :  this.state = {CodigoDigitado: '' }   and ...this.state.codigoDigitado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are logging `condigoDigitado` and not `CodigoDigitado`. Also, try to use camelCase for variable and function names and try to use english terms in your code (variables, functions, etc.)

```
handleInputChangeCodigo(event){
   this.setState({CodigoDigitado: event.target.value})
   console.log('Digitando: '+ this.state.codigoDigitado)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was it.
I have little experience in JS. I ended up falling for it, but I'm going to adopt a standard.